# Eszett (ß) in Android App

Tags: android

The german "ß"character in my res/layout/activity.. file gets automaticly converted to "ss" in my app. Even if I set my language and keyboard to German it still won't show up. Is it possible to show a "ß" in Android?

edit:

```
<Button android:text="ß" .../>
```

edit 2:

i fixed it: in German there is no capital version of "ß", only lower case. version. Buttons are however by default upper case. So android converts it to "SS". Therefore only `android:textAllCaps="false"` needs to be added to my button xml.

link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E

Comment: Of course it is. Are we talking of the IDE, a text file, an xml resource or a database?

Comment: All of the above must be configured and/or saved to use the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: The character does show up in the IDE and xml resource file. But when I put the app on my phone it is converted to "ss".

Comment: You might want to try `<Button android:text="\u03b2" .../>`

Comment: Anyway, since there is **no rule** on when to use `ß` (sz ligature, beta or Esszet) and when `ss`, I wouldn't focus too much on it. If you are searching a word and you write "straße", but in the db ther is "strasse", there would be no match. So, it would be nice if Android is smart enough to do a bidirectional conversion and let `ß` become `ss`. Note that `this doesn't happen with umlauted vowels`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see you found the solution to your problem; may I suggest you add it as an answer, in the "Answer" box below?

Comment: \u03b2 is the code for the lower case greek letter beta which looks like "ß" but is not quite the same. &#223; does convert to "ß"

Comment: For me, beta and sz are really the same... ;)

Comment: different question, but very much related, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761404/eszett-%C3%9F-in-android-app-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i fixed it: in German there is no capital version of "ß", only lower case. version. Buttons are however by default upper case. So android converts it to "SS". Therefore only `android:textAllCaps="false"` needs to be added to my button xml.

link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E