# Eszett (ß) in Android App (2)

Tags: android

I have a span like this:

```
 private SpannableStringBuilder spandex(List<String> ret, Boolean startDark) {
    SpannableStringBuilder spanBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    Spannable span = null;
    int color = 0;
    int startDarkMod = 0;
    if(startDark)
        startDarkMod = 1;
    for (String x : ret) {

        if ((ret.indexOf(x) + startDarkMod) % 2 > 0)
            color = WzTheme.NOT_HIGHLIGHTED_COLOR;
        else
            color = WzTheme.ALT_NOT_HIGHLIGHTED_COLOR;

        span = new SpannableString(x.toUpperCase());
        span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color),
                0,
                x.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spanBuilder.append(span);
    }

    return spanBuilder;
}


public static int NOT_HIGHLIGHTED_COLOR = Color.rgb(68, 68, 68);
public static int ALT_NOT_HIGHLIGHTED_COLOR = Color.rgb(110, 110, 110);
```

It produces light gray and dark grey code like this:
[image: screen shot galaxy5 activity]

Then there is that bright white "T".  It happens after every ß character, which, as the [other thread mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180420/eszett-%C3%9F-in-android-app), gets converted to SS when capitalized.  I would prefer no capatalization of that char, but I can live with the conversion to SS.  What I need to stop from happening is the big white "T".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ugh, this fixes it:

```
private String myUpperCase(String word) {
    word = word.replaceAll("ß", "XXX");
    return word.toUpperCase().replaceAll("XXX", "ß");
}
```

so as you probably already know, the issue is that ß gets expanded to SS in java utf-8 toUpperCase() and that increases the length of the string in the span by one, but "x" (in my code above) is one char short (length) so i get the default white text.

i am happy with the fix.